# Why do I receive an error with this API request?

Tags: node.js, api

I am not entering my if (!error) statement, I know this because my console.log('in query') statement is not printing.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs= require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();
var crunchbase = require('crunchbase2');
var apikey='myapikey';

crunchbase.init(apikey);
console.log('after init');

crunchbase.people( {query: "1" }, function(error, results) {
  console.log('in .people');
    if (!error) {
      console.log('in query');
      console.log(results) // Print the search results                                              
  }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

more details on error:

> **SyntaxError:** Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/crunchbase/node_modules/crunchbase2/index.js:73:28)
>       at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/crunchbase/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Request. (/home/ubuntu/crunchbase/node_modules/request/request.js:1035:10)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/ubuntu/crunchbase/node_modules/request/request.js:962:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at _stream_readable.js:944:16
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)

Comment: note: myapikey contains my actual key. Specifically the error is "unexpected token"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are reaching till  **"in .people"**

debug it by checking the value of error variable and then change you if condition like one i provided

```
var express = require('express');
var fs= require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();
var crunchbase = require('crunchbase2');
var apikey='myapikey';

crunchbase.init(apikey);
console.log('after init');

crunchbase.people( {query: "1" }, function(error, results) {
  console.log('in .people');
  console.log(error);
    if (error) {
      console.log('in query');

  }
console.log(results) // Print the search results   
});
```

this might be a better way to code and as your information you have a error variable that contain some information so your if condtion not working